# General method for parametrising as a ruled surface or showing a surface to be ruled

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm sorry for asking such a basic question, but a practice question I'm currently completing asks for me to give a local parametrisation of $H = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} \vert x^2 - y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$ as a ruled surface.

The only method I have seen for this is to write:
$\beta(s) = (x_0, y_0, z_0)^T + s (u,v,w)^T$ and to then just plug this into the equation of the surface. However, doing this yields the simultaneous equations:

$u^2 - v^2 + w^2 = 0$

$ux_0 - vy_0 + wz_0 = 0 $

From which I got: $w = v \sqrt{\dfrac{y_0^2 - x_0^2}{z_0^2 + x_0^2}}$

And so, $u = v \sqrt{\dfrac{2x_0^2+z_0^2 - y_0^2}{z_0^2 + x_0^2}} $

So that would mean that $\beta(s) = (x_0, y_0, z_0)^T + s ( \sqrt{\dfrac{2x_0^2+z_0^2 - y_0^2}{z_0^2 + x_0^2}},1,\sqrt{\dfrac{y_0^2 - x_0^2}{z_0^2 + x_0^2}})^T$ is a line passing through the initial point, but I'm incredibly dubious about this method and the result thereof.

What would be a good systematic approach to this question. Also, if the method I have outlined above is valid, where has my working gone awry?

Comment: Just a comment: Given a surface $S$ of the form $S = \{(x,y,z) \colon F(x,y,z) = 1\}$, I think it can be tricky to figure out whether or not $S$ is ruled.  Even if you know in advance that $S$ is ruled, I'm not sure whether there exists a "general method" for deriving an explicit parametrization of $S$ as a ruled surface.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Thanks! I'm also a bit confused as to what exactly constitutes a "local parametrisation". Isn't a line such as the one I've given (if it's valid) a local (very local!) parametrisation of the surface?

Comment: Why not find the intersection of a tangent plane of the surface (at an arbitrary point) with the surface?